# How to hide and display when ever onclick function happen by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing one html page inside that I am using javascript also , what my requirement is when ever the page is loading the first div should be displayed when ever I click on that icon it should hide and it displays the second div content,for that please help me to fix the issue..

```
<div class="first">
<i class="fa fa-heart" onclick="toggle()" ></i>
</div>
<div class="second">
<b> I am from second div</b>
<div>

<script>
flag=true;
here I am not getting how to write the function to achieve my task
</script>
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: SO is not a "please code this for me" forum. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do it. The 2 I normally use are:

1. Wrapping the icon into label and adding `<input type="checkbox" />`. This allows to achieve it without using any javascript at all, but it has a bit of complex css to it. You can check out this https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/ for reference.
2. This is easy to do. You need to define `.active { display: block }` class in your css and in javascript you can write something like

```js
function toggle() {
  var element = document.querySelector(".second");
  element.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

but before you need to make `.second { display: none }`

I am sure that there're more ways of doing this, but these are the 2 I use the most depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Your toggle function could be like this:

```
function toggle() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('second');
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I would suggest using and `id` on the element instead of a class as it is explained here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: On click of the icon it should be hidden but if I use this function it won't be hidden